# Want to know how to populate data from One block to another?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have two database Datablock

In the First Block I have a Item called parameter name with LOV. While selecting that LOV ,it should populate Next Item Also that is Section

Now What i want is when I am selecting the Parameter name LOV from First Data Block. I want to populate the corresponding data in the list Value of the Second Data Block

For this i used post text item -->Inside that I used go block But it throws illegal restriction Error

Now I am out of ideas

Comment: There was no image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you're talking about *cascading LoVs*. If that's so, then the 1st LoV query looks like this:

```
select parameter_name, section
from some_table
where some_condition;
```

You set it to populate appropriate fields in the 1st data block (one of them is `:block_1.parameter_name`).

---

The second block's LoV would then "reference" the first block's field:

```
select another_column
from another_table
where parameter_name = :block_1.parameter_name     --> this
  and other_conditions;
```

---

You don't need any triggers; once you display 2nd block field's list of values, it'll use that `where` clause and display only values that match the condition.